# Why there is no search bar appear in palatte in the Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, palette

Android Studio screenshot. where I am facing the issue .

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about design choices that border a feature request are appropriate in an issue tracker - not here

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window -> Restore Default Layout.

Or you could try <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

Tested on Android Studio 4.2.2